# Obtain a matrix from a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, cluster-analysis

I'm working on clustering and I need to tranform my data in matrix.
This is my df:

```
       el1 el2 value
    1   a   x     1
    2   a   y     2
    3   a   z     3
    2   b   x     2
    3   b   y     3
    3   b   z     3
```

I need to transform it in matrix, having el1 and el2 as rows and cols names and the corresponding value.

```
  x y z 
a 1 2 3
b 2 3 3
```

How I can do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `reshape2` and some magic (I created my own data)

```
df=read.table(text="
el1 el2 value
a   w     1
a   x     2
a   y     3
a   z     4
b   x     1
b   y     2
b   z     3
c   y     1
c   z     2
d   z     1",h=T)
```

then

```
library(reshape2)
df2=dcast(
  df,
  el1~el2,
  value.var="value"
)
rownames(df2)=df2$el1
df2=subset(df2,select=-c(el1))

   w  x  y z
a  1  2  3 4
b NA  1  2 3
c NA NA  1 2
d NA NA NA 1
```

if your original data only contains data for the upper or lower triangle of a matrix then you can copy the other with

```
df2[lower.tri(df2)]=t(df2)[lower.tri(df2)]
```

Comment: It works, and I obtain only the upper side of the matrix. What if I would like  to "copy" values also in the lower side?

Comment: @PersianK What do you mean by "the upper side of the matrix"?

Comment: el1 and el2 are equal so I should obtain a simmetric matrix

Comment: yes, sorry, I was meaning the upper triangle (first time I'm trying to do clustering). So, yes I would liko to turn NA values in the lower triangle in numeric value, just copying them from the upper triangle

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using ´xtabs`

```
> xtabs(value ~ ., df)
   el2
el1 x y z
  a 1 2 3
  b 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on `tidyr`'s `pivot_wider` function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

res <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = el1,
    names_from = el2,
    values_from = value) %>% 
  data.frame()

rownames(res) <- res$el1

(res %<>% select(-el1))

  x y z
a 1 2 3
b 2 3 3
```

It needs a little bit of work because tibbles do not like row names.